# how to insert paragraphs with different positions - itext

Tags: java, netbeans, itext

The drawing of the table is done correctly but it gets wrong as the data is repeated.
the barcode has to be like this to avoid errors from employees checking wrong codes.

[image]

The ideal would be A picture speaks a thousand words.

[image]

My function:

```
Document documentoPDF = new Document();

    try {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(documentoPDF, new FileOutputStream("c:\\exporta_Celso\\contagem_" + jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString() + ".pdf"));
        documentoPDF.open();
        documentoPDF.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        table.setTotalWidth(documentoPDF.getPageSize().getWidth());

        for (int i = 0; i < itens.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(((List) itens.get(i)).get(0).toString());
            System.out.println(((List) itens.get(i)).get(1).toString());
            String item = ((List) itens.get(i)).get(1).toString();

            BarcodeEAN codeEAN = new BarcodeEAN();

            codeEAN.setCodeType(codeEAN.EAN13);
            String barCodeBruto = ((List) itens.get(i)).get(0).toString();
            String barCode = null;
            if (barCodeBruto.length() != 13) {
                barCode = ("0000000000000" + barCodeBruto).substring(barCodeBruto.length());
            } else {
                barCode = barCodeBruto;
            }
            codeEAN.setCode(barCode);
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

            Image imageEAN = codeEAN.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);

            PdfPCell cellBar = new PdfPCell(imageEAN);
            PdfPCell cellDesc = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(item));
            PdfPCell cellQtd = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("QTD."));

            cellBar.setPadding(3);
            cellBar.setUseDescender(true);
            cellBar.setUseAscender(true);

            cellDesc.setPadding(3);
            cellDesc.setUseDescender(true);
            cellDesc.setUseAscender(true);

            cellQtd.setPadding(3);
            cellQtd.setUseDescender(true);
            cellQtd.setUseAscender(true);

            float height = table.calculateHeights();
            float width = documentoPDF.getPageSize().getWidth();

            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                float[] widths = new float[]{145f, width - 36 - 10f, 80f};
                table.setWidths(widths);

                table.addCell(cellBar);
                table.addCell(cellDesc);
                table.addCell(cellQtd);


            }else{
                float[] widths = new float[]{80f, width - 36 - 10f, 145f};
                table.setWidths(widths);

                table.addCell(cellQtd);
                table.addCell(cellDesc);
                table.addCell(cellBar);
            }

            PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();

            ColumnText columnText = new ColumnText(canvas);
            columnText.setSimpleColumn(36, 756 - height, width - 36, 36);
            columnText.addElement(table);
            columnText.go();
        }

    } catch (DocumentException de) {
        de.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        documentoPDF.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a parent table outside the looping.

`PdfPTable tableFinal = new PdfPTable(1);
tableFinal.setWidthPercentage(100);
tableFinal.setTotalWidth(documentoPDF.getPageSize().getWidth());

tableFinal.addCell(table);                
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
ColumnText columnText = new ColumnText(canvas);
columnText.setSimpleColumn(36, 756 - height, width - 36, 36);
columnText.addElement(tableFinal);
columnText.go();`